# Kentico - Profile picture of user from facebook Web part

Tags: kentico

I am using Kentico built in web part "Facebook Connect Logon" on my website. I have made all the required settings for facebook in Settings application.

I have provided all the token access in the developers facebook account for the application.

The functionality is working fine, I just want to know is it possible to get the profile picture of the user from their facebook account and use it on my website?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the format specified for the [Facebook user image](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.0/user/picture) in their API.

```
{user-id}/picture
```

Then use the type parameter to customise the size.